# read count of same response messages in thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have thread group with single sampler.I have a scenario with 10 users to run for 1 hour duration. in view results tree showing different response data in every sampler's response data.can it possible to count how many times samplers get same response data.

```
         {"success":false,"code":"104","message":"xx","status":412,"MessageType":"120","ResponseCode":"100","rilreplyDetails":"121"}
```

{"success":false,"code":"104","message":"yyy","status":412,"MessageType":"120","ResponseCode":"100","rilreplyDetails":"121"}

can I get a count of how many samplers get"xx" response,and how many for "yyy"?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to define two variables in the Test Plan section, i.e: **counter_xx** and **counter_yyy**.

[image]

Then on the sampler request add one Regular Expression Extractor to extract the message value and finally use If Controller to specify which counter to increment.

The below image shows the structure for above solution.

[image]

Finally, you would be able to access the variable values by using ${counter_xx} or ${counter_yyy}.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be doing this outside of JMeter, i.e. configure it to save response data by adding the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up. Once your test is done inspect the resulting .jtl result file using your favorite XML editor.

See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) for more information on the approach.

---

Another option is using [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and the script like:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable
import org.apache.jmeter.functions.IterationCounter

def xxcounter = props.get("xxcounter")
if (xxcounter == null) {
    xxcounter = new IterationCounter();
    List<CompoundVariable> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new CompoundVariable("false"));
    xxcounter.setParameters(params);
}
def yycounter = props.get('yycounter')
if (yycounter == null) {
    yycounter = new IterationCounter();
    List<CompoundVariable> params = new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(new CompoundVariable("false"));
    yycounter.setParameters(params);
}

if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('xx')) {
    log.info('XX count: ' + xxcounter.execute(prev, sampler))
    props.put('xxcounter', xxcounter)
}
if (prev.getResponseDataAsString().contains('yyy')) {
    log.info('YYY count: ' + yycounter.execute(prev, sampler))
    props.put('yycounter', yycounter)
}
```

The listener will scan current sampler response data and increment either this or that counter printing the current value to *jmeter.log* file.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Increment Counter Conditionally]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)